# Missing class: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference. R8:Warning

Tags: android-studio, jackson, android-r8

After I updated Android Studio to 3.5, I am facing below warning whenever I build my Project.

> Missing class: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference

[image]

My project is using **AndroidX**. Here is the gist for  my **build.gradle**(app)
https://gist.github.com/Arkar009/4ae5a05ff3435636bc605fee1fbdb050 . Can anyone know why this error occurs or alternative ideas to solve this error? Thanks in advances.

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems to only be a warning. Can you add the application gradle file so we can see the import statement?

Comment: @tomerpacific, I already update the question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any imports for Jackson in the gist you attached. Do you have it as a local jar?

Comment: @tomerpacific, I used only jcenter library except printing library one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're super sure you will remember this line if you include Jackson later in your project, this does the trick (add it in your project's proguard-project.[txt|pro] file):

```
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
```

That class gets included somehow in the missing classes Set in R8 (I didn't go that far in R8's code), but you can skip the warning if you get that class in the list of patterns for "Don't Warn" rules (see com/android/tools/r8/R8.java):

```
  List<ProguardConfigurationRule> synthesizedProguardRules = new ArrayList<>();
  timing.begin("Strip unused code");
  Set<DexType> classesToRetainInnerClassAttributeFor = null;
  try {
    Set<DexType> missingClasses = appView.appInfo().getMissingClasses();
    missingClasses = filterMissingClasses(
        missingClasses, options.getProguardConfiguration().getDontWarnPatterns());
    if (!missingClasses.isEmpty()) {
      missingClasses.forEach(
          clazz -> {
            options.reporter.warning(
                new StringDiagnostic("Missing class: " + clazz.toSourceString()));
          });
```

TBH, I was also bugged enough by this warning to get into R8, hope it helps!